# Multisite image URLs incorrect in editor

Tags: images, multisite, redirect, block-editor, regex

I've been driving myself nuts with this one, so I'm hoping someone might be able to help.

I have a Multisite with the latest WordPress version set to subfolders. The issue I am experiencing is with images in the post editor - I am using a vanilla block editor off the shelf.

Let's say I have the setup below, where each is its own blog within the network.

```
example.com
example.com/product-a/
example.com/product-b/
```

When a user uploads an image to the Product B blog (as an example), in the file system it is properly saves to `example.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/03/2022/09/someimage.jpg`. If I go to this URL then the image is visible, and when I publish a post it works with no issue.

*However*, in the post editor I get broken image placeholders. When I inspect it in Chrome, the broken editor image points to `example.com/product-b/wp-content/uploads/sites/04/2022/09/someimage.jpg`.

Everything I've read has had me looking at the `.htaccess` file, but for the life of me I can't figure out what's wrong. Here's my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Any help would be great - thank you in advance!

Comment: The .htaccess file looks fine — this has to do with the image URL saving differently than the location where the file is uploaded, or so it seems. Do the files appear correctly in the media library?

Comment: @NabhaCosley Yep, they appear just fine which is another point of confusion. I've managed a lot of different multisites and single sites and just haven't seen this behavior before. My next step is to go through the AWS infrastructure and see if there isn't something throwing a wrench in how images operate, so figures crossed (and thanks for verifying that I'm not ENTIRELY crazy about .htaccess) :)

Comment: If you're desperate, you could also step through the code in the WP core that handles uploading and adding metadata and see if you can spot where the metadata diverges from the upload directory (if indeed it does — have you checked that?). Because it's handled through AJAX, one way to do this is to add `var_dump()` statements followed by `wp_die()`, then look at the AJAX responses when you upload images. It's tedious but it does work.